# How can I copy complex directories with PowerShell's robocopy, including exception files?

Tags: powershell, multiprocessing, robocopy

I have a problem in a complex copy.

Below is an example of my script and CSV with source and destination paths. The powershell script I created works well in part but not totally, it makes the copies based on the CSV, however in the example we see the directories "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022" need to be copied to the destination directory "Archive" and the directory "2023" under the destination directory "Years", so far the script is doing its job.

CSV model
 `Source;Destination "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2018";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\Archives\2018" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2019";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\Archives\2018" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2020";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\Archives\2020" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2021";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\Archives\2021" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2022";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\Archives\2022" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\Years\2023";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\Years\2023" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2018";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\Archives\2018" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2019";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\Archives\2018" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2020";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\Archives\2020" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2021";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\Archives\2021" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2022";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\Archives\2022" "\\data.valampe.com\Information technology\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2023";"\\data.valampe.com\UIT\Robotics Department\AI Lab\2023"`

Script model

`# Delete all existing variables
Remove-Variable -Name * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"`

`# Request Business name`
$BUsinessLineName = Read-Host "Enter the Business name without space and without special characters"

`# Path to CSV file containing source and destination information $csvPath = "E:\powershell command\CopyMultifolders\MultifoldersEncryptedTest.csv"`

`# Read CSV file with specified delimiter (;) $csvContent = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath -Delimiter ";"`

`# Report name log $reportName = $BUsinessLineName + "_" + $date + "_Test.log"  $sourcelogs = "E:\powershell command\CopyMultifolders\Logs\" + $reportName`

`# Create an associative array to store previously copied directories $copiedDirectories = @{}`

`# Browse each line of the CSV file and make the copy foreach ($row in $csvContent) {`

`# Get source and destination paths for each line
$sourcePath = $row.Source.Trim('"')
$destinationPath = $row.Destination.Trim('"')

```
Write-Host "Source: $sourcePath"
Write-Host "Destination: $destinationPath"`
```

`# Check if the destination directory already exists if (Test-Path $destinationPath) { Write-Host "Skipping copy of directory: $sourcePath (already exists at $destinationPath)" continue }`

`# Check if the directory has already been copied to this destination if ($copiedDirectories.ContainsKey($destinationPath) -and $copiedDirectories[$destinationPath] -contains $sourcePath) { Write-Host "Skipping copy of directory: $sourcePath (already copied to $destinationPath)" continue }`

`# Copy source directory to destination chcp 1252 robocopy $sourcePath $destinationPath /E /r:0 /w:0 /XO /XJ /XJF /XD ~BROMIUM* /XF sourceonefilesmanifest* ~$*.* /LOG:$sourcelogs`

`# Check if the source directory copy was successful if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) { Write-Host "Failed to copy directory: $sourcePath" } else { Write-Host "Successfully copied directory: $sourcePath" # Add the copied directory to the table of copied directories if ($copiedDirectories.ContainsKey($destinationPath)) { $copiedDirectories[$destinationPath] += $sourcePath } else { $copiedDirectories[$destinationPath] = @($sourcePath) } } }`

However, the parent source directories "Years" & "AI Lab" contain files which, unfortunately, are not copied. Another problem is that during incremental copies the source files/directories that could potentially be modified during the incremental copy phase are not updated at the destination. Could someone help me?

Comment: TLDR: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please property [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your question, [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/tourhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As an aside, `RoboCopy.exe` is **not** Powershell. In PowerShell it is a general advise to use [cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) as e.g. [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) above external comands as `RoboCopy`.

Comment: Power shell does not use ! for the not operation.  Instead you use -not : if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) { Write-Host "Failed to copy directory: $sourcePath" }

Comment: @jdweng,  `!` and `-not` can be used _interchangeably_ for logical negation in PowerShell. See [about_Logical_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators). Please familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of PowerShell before posting such comments.

Comment: @mklement0 : I do not believe the documentations.  There are 1000 of inconsistencies in PS.  PS is another Microsoft Tool that you have to be a GURU to get code to work or just keep on trying different methods until you find one that works.  I've been working with Microsoft tools for over 40 years and often have to buy books from GURUs like Norton who knew that actual code and tricks that you had to use to get code to work.  You shouldn't have to rely on tricks to get software to work.   Code be well documented and work consistently like on UNIX.

Comment: @jdweng, `!` is no trick. It is a by-design, documented alternative to `-not` and is widely used. With trivial effort you could have verified that it works (e.g. `! $true`). Please consider deleting your off-topic rant.